# How to seek a .ts file in vlc media player integrated in android application?

Tags: android, vlc, libvlc

I have used vlc media player integration in my android app (libvlc). I use it to play rtsp files which are in .ts format.I have implemented a feature in which I can playback the recorded files and it works fine only for playing but I can not seek through these files even though they are seek-able in vlc desktop version. To clarify this I played that stream on vlc android app and still I can not seek through it then I used Mx player android app and I can seek in this file.
Is there a way to do this in vlc integration for android?

```
 private LibVLC libvlc;
 private MediaController controller;

private void CreateMediaplayer(String url, TextureView textureview)
    {
        try {
            ArrayList<String> options = new ArrayList<String>();
            options.add("--rtsp-tcp");
            options.add("-vvv"); // verbosity
       /*   options.add("--aout=opensles");
            options.add("--audio-time-stretch"); // time stretching
            options.add("--aout=opensles");
            options.add("--avcodec-codec=h264");*/

            controller = new MediaController(this.context);
            controller.setMediaPlayer(playerinterface);
            controller.setAnchorView(relativeLayout);

            if(isFullscreen){
                controller.show(100000);

            }

            libvlc = new LibVLC(this.context, options);
            // Create media player
            mMediaPlayer = new MediaPlayer(libvlc);
            mMediaPlayer.setEventListener(this);



            // Set up video output
            final IVLCVout vout = mMediaPlayer.getVLCVout();
            mMediaPlayer.setScale(0);
            vout.detachViews();
            vout.setVideoView(textureview);
            vout.setWindowSize(textureview.getWidth(), textureview.getHeight());
            vout.attachViews();
            textureview.setKeepScreenOn(true);

            Media m = new Media(libvlc, Uri.parse(url));
            mMediaPlayer.setMedia(m);
            mMediaPlayer.play();

            progressBar.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            }catch(Exception e1)
        {
            progressBar.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        }

    }
 private MediaController.MediaPlayerControl playerinterface = new MediaController.MediaPlayerControl() {
        @Override
        public void start() {
           // mMediaPlayer.pause();
        }

        @Override
        public void pause() {
          // mMediaPlayer.play();

        }

        @Override
        public int getDuration() {
            return 0;
            //return (int)mMediaPlayer.getLength();
        }

        @Override
        public int getCurrentPosition() {
            return 0;
        }

        @Override
        public void seekTo(int i) {
            mMediaPlayer.setPosition((float)i);
            mMediaPlayer.play();

        }

        @Override
        public boolean isPlaying() {
            return false;
        }

        @Override
        public int getBufferPercentage() {
            return 0;
        }

        @Override
        public boolean canPause() {
            return true;
        }

        @Override
        public boolean canSeekBackward() {
            return true;
        }

        @Override
        public boolean canSeekForward() {
            return true;
        }

        @Override
        public int getAudioSessionId() {
            return 0;
        }
    };
```

Comment: Please share your logs, and possibly the sample

Comment: I have added the code, the media player plays anything which is provided to it in the url. The main problem is that the media controls seek bar does not seek this stream.Sometimes it just plays the stream from starting.

Comment: Please re-read my comment.

Comment: Thank you so much for helping but I solved this problem the thing was that vlc is unable to find out the total duration of the video clip that's why it can't seek it. So I somehow find way to define the duration from my own.